# Elmah not sending Email

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, elmah

I have implemented Elmah in my Mvc4 application.My web.config is as follows:-

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
      <sectionGroup name="elmah">
          <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
          <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
          <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
          <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      </sectionGroup>        
  </configSections>

    <elmah>
        <security allowRemoteAccess="1" />
        <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data"/>
        <errorMail from="test@test.in" to="test1@test.in" subject="Elmah Report" async="true" smtpServer="mail.test.in" />            
    </elmah>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Mvcjquery-20130225111502;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
  </connectionStrings>   

    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
          <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />         
      </httpHandlers>

      <httpModules>
          <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
          <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah"/>

     </httpModules>        
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
      <modules>
          <add name="Elmah.ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
          <add name="Elmah.ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      </modules>

      <handlers>
          <add name="Elmah" path="elmah.axd" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />         
      </handlers>
  </system.webServer>    

</configuration>
```

I have added code to send email via elmah.I can see errors by typing in url localhost://elmah.axd.But am not getting mail.Pls help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with `async="false"`:

```
<errorMail 
    from="join@assert.in" 
    to="twinkle@assert.in" 
    subject="Elmah Report" 
    async="false" 
    smtpServer="mail.assert.in" />
```

Comment: I got an exception "SmtpException was unhandled by user code". Failure sending mail.

Comment: Alright, so take a look at the InnerException. Maybe you have problems with the SMTP server that you configured.

Comment: ya..it was the problem with my SMTP server.Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Will setting async to false change the operation of a website as far as a user is concerned?  ie will Elmah still fail silently?